# Replace single file of external meteor package

Tags: javascript, meteor, svg, package, iron-router

I'm using the iron-router package for my meteor app.

```
api.use(['iron:router@1.0.12'], 'client');
```

But I need this correction (https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-location/pull/18/files) for my iron-router to let my app work correctly with svg hyperlinks.

Unfortunately this commit isn't accepted so far. That means I have to use 'my own' `location.js`.

To be more precise, it is part of `iron:location`.

What is the best way to add this needed part/package/file to my meteor app while keeping the `iron:router` package? I would like to replace this single file until it is merged to the package.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried to use a local version of the package with your changes? If you have, did you encounter any difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a packages folder under your meteor project folder
2. Clone iron:location into a new folder called "location" in the packages folder
3. Edit the file as needed, or just grab the specific version from github

Why? Meteor looks in the packages directory in the local project folder first, then looks elsewhere. If you want to be really sure, bump the version on package.js to 1.0.13 in the package you just cloned, then edit the .meteor/packages file: iron:router@1.0.13 or at the line where you're adding the package, like this: api.use(['iron:router@1.0.13'], 'client');